# Kubernetes API for CustomResourceDefinition to perform CRUD methods

Tags: kubernetes

How can I perform CRUD methods on CustomResourceDefinition

I've tried doing like below but it's not working

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/v1/namespaces/test/CustomResourceDefinition
```

Error:

```
{  
   "kind":"Status",
   "apiVersion":"v1",
   "metadata":{  

   },
   "status":"Failure",
   "message":"the server could not find the requested resource",
   "reason":"NotFound",
   "details":{  

   },
   "code":404
}
```

Comment: not create what you want? do you want CRUD on CRD or CRD object?

Comment: I've Created CRD, I want to GET, and DELETE that CRD using API commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions/{crd-name}
```

If you have a CRD named `database.eloquent.com`, replace `{crd-name}` with `database.eloquent.com`

To get all CRDs,

```
$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1/customresourcedefinitions
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm able to get the pods using below command.                                                                                                                                                                                             `$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pods | jq`                                                                                                               
 in the same way, I tried to get CRD's using below command but it's not working.                      
`$ curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/v1/customresourcedefinitions | jq`

Comment: what? didn't get you

Comment: If tried to GET the pods runing on the cluster it's returing the all pods details (first command in above comment), Where as for customresourcedefinitions it's returning 404 status code (second command in above comment)

Comment: Hi Aerokite, the command u gave. It's works now I have to https instred http

Comment: now that the feature is matured replace v1beta1 with v1. `apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1/customresourcedefinitions/`